# What is this plant with highly variable 3-5 lobed palmate, smooth edged leaves?

Tags: identification

This plant blew in months ago and quickly grew up. The shape of the leaves vary. No two leaves look exactly the same in profile but usually has the same basic form but often one of the lobes are missing. Typically about 5 lobes.

Now believed to be palmate. Maybe pinnate?

It has smooth edges and is shiny. Edges curve under slightly.

[image]

Further information from previous comments:

- Found in my garden in Western US. It randomly grew in. We have a lot of strange things "blow" in like lantanas of different colors, snapdragons, petunias, a basil, etc...
- the leaves do look kind of like a fig.
- It is less than a year old and has had no fruit we have noticed.
- Next door neighbor has a fig tree but this plant does not look like their variety which has large and broad leaves.
- Currently thinking maybe a hybrid, mutant, or still undetermined variety of fig or fig-like plant.

Can anyone find anything more definitive than fig-like?

Comment: Leaves look figgy: https://www.google.com/search?q=fig+leaves&biw=1627&bih=820&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjGuPPXw9_PAhWC2SYKHU2uAQcQ_AUIBigB Not sure how that would blow in.

Comment: It does kind of look like a ficus carica but not quite. Maybe a hybrid/mutant? One of our neigbhors over the wall (houses have brick walls dividing them) have some type of fig but the leaves are a large and broad variation - this does not look like their tree. I've had no fruit on it but it is less than a year old.      .... Perhaps a bird 'dropped' in a hybrid seed from the neighbors?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is Ficus carica.  [Ficus carica](http://lh2treeid.blogspot.com/2010/04/ficus-carica-common-fig.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is [Abelmoschus moschatus subsp. tuberosus](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Abelmoschus%20moschatus%20subsp.%20tuberosus&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=960&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd3LGLkerPAhUISSYKHb9QCEcQ_AUIBigB#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=Abelmoschus%20moschatus%20subsp.%20tuberosus%20leaves).

[image]

Comment: Looks like the flower will tell the story here.